# How can I force a TOS to appear on first boot?

Tags: open-source, git, github, login, boot

I work for a corporate technologies company and we are in the process of sending out desktops to client. This client has a history of claiming lost or missing computers and we would like to see when the computer is turned on for the first time.

Is there any software or github reference that we could use so that when the user turns on the computer for the first time after we configure it they have to read through a Terms of Service and sign in order to log in?